# Unity5. How to import scripts?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am following this tutorial:

```
http://www.raywenderlich.com/25205/beginning-unity-3d-for-ios-part-13
```

In the middle of it, there is

```
 Assets\Import Package\Scripts\SmoothFollow.js
```

part.

but I guess that menu is gone for Unity 5?

Where did SmoothFollow.js go ??

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the Standard Assets to get the standard import packages.
See here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/917023/unity-5-standard-assets-are-missing.html